# Variational autoencoder - comparative analysis of code

Tags: keras, autoencoder

Could you comment two version of variational autoencoder loss and show me why they give me different results?

Dataset:

```py
data1 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype='int32')

data2 = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype='int32')


data3 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype='int32')
```

100 samples each, so I have 300 samples.

Code 1:

```py
def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
    xent_loss = objectives.binary_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean)
    kl_loss = -0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var))
    loss = xent_loss + kl_loss
    return loss

vae.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=vae_loss)
```

Code 2:

```py
    def zero_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return K.zeros_like(y_pred)

    class CustomVariationalLayer(Layer):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            self.is_placeholder = True
            super(CustomVariationalLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def vae_loss(self, x, x_decoded_mean):
        xent_loss = original_dim * metrics.binary_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean)
K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
        return K.mean(xent_loss + kl_loss)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs[0]
        x_decoded_mean = inputs[1]
        loss = self.vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean)
        self.add_loss(loss, inputs=inputs)

        return K.ones_like(x)

loss_layer = CustomVariationalLayer()([x, x_decoded_mean])
vae = Model(x, [loss_layer])
vae.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=[zero_loss])
```

Results are so different and I don't see where? Latent dimension are different. Code 2 shows the separation between groups and code 1 not.
code 1, vae.predict... is not accurate and code 2 give me 1 on all features.
Code 2 gives me accurate feedback of the code:

```py
sent_encoded = encoder.predict(np.array(test), batch_size = batch_size)
sent_decoded = generator.predict(sent_encoded)
```

and code 1 is not accurate at all.

Both experiments have the same layers. So, once again, where is the different and what is the best solution for dataset like described above?